# Export a variable from my Node JS server which uses express so that I can access it my client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Is there a way to send a variable from my Node JS server which uses express so that I can access it my client side?

I want this variable to store a local value from the server and access it from my client side javascript.

I have found out that

> app.locals.environment = 'myValue'

can set a local value in my server. Is there any way to access it in my client side? I'm using a react architecture in my client side code.

Comment: Unless you are doing some server side rendering, you can't.

Comment: Client need to fetch any resource it want from user. For that you have to create an API and call it when you need the value.
And if you want it whenver it gets change then you have to use some service like socket.io..

Comment: How often do you want to access the variable? just on page load? or dynamically? If it's just on page load you can simply supply it to the html <script>myVariable=""</script>. If you want to access it dynamically, then you could set up an ajax response to return the variable. If you want to manipulate the variable on the client side and change the node server then you can also do that via an ajax callback.

Answer (score 1):

The server and client are completely separate entities which only communicate by sending messages to each other.

You need to encode the data in the variable as a string and then send it to the browser, which needs to be prepared to handle the response.

Usually those messages are sent in HTTP but sometimes other technologies (WebSockets being the most common) are used.

You can't initiate HTTP from the server (it's a request->response system), but the browser could request a page which include the data …

- Expressed in the form of an embedded `<script>` which sets a global variable
- As an attribute value on some element (such as `<body data-foo="bar">`)

… or you could make an Ajax response from the browser and present a suitable serialised format (e.g. JSON).

If you want to initiate the request from the server, look at WebSockets (and in particular at Socket.IO which wraps around them).

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [response API](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals) from express : the res.locals will help you

Comment: That just attaches a variable to the object representing the request on the server. The data never gets sent back to the browser so the client can't do anything with it.

Comment: I understood the question was to send data from client to server.

Comment: The question says "from my Node JS server" and "so that I can access it my client side" … and `res.locals` isn't useful for your interpretation of it either.

Comment: "can set a local value in my server. Is there any way to access it in my client side?"